# regular expression to break in tokens but not string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a query string and I want to know of its tokens. For that I tried regex

```
opt = /([+-/%=|!&<>(),\[\]])/g;
```

and it is working perfectly but it is also creating tokens inside string.

Example:

```
var str = "SUM(1, one) + 12 + three";
["SUM", "(", "1", ",", " one", ")", " ", "+", " 12 ", "+", " three"]
```

But when these parameters are inside string I don't want them to break but right now it is doing:
Example:

```
 var str = = "SUM(1, one) + 12 + three + 'Hello + world'";
["SUM", "(", "1", ",", " one", ")", " ", "+", " 12 ", "+", " three ", "+", " 'Hello ", "+", " world'"]
```

I don't want "'Hello ", "+", " world'" as separate token. I want  "'Hello + world'" as single token.Basically I want to tokenize variable and replace them with my varibles without affecting string.

Comment: there is no regex for this, you will have to do it by parsing char-by-char and match together if tokens inside quotes are found

Comment: Can you help me some library to do this. except esprima as It can contain excel if condition also.

Comment: Try `s.match(/(?:'[^']*'|[^-+\/%=|!&<>(),[\]])+/g)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sIcfbq/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this regex cannot account for quote escaping inside quoted strings which is possible and counts as valid string. But if OP is sure these conditions will not be present maybe can do

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew. I tried your regex and it is giving matching parameters. How can I use it to split and get tokens.

Comment: You have already accepted an answer, I guess it does what you need.

Comment: Yes. It is doing well but we can have multiple relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your quotes are balanced and unescaped, you may use this regex using a lookahead:

```
/([-+\/%=|!&<>(),\[\]])(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jlVJxq/1)

```js
var str = "SUM(1, one) + 12 + three + 'Hello + world'";

var re = /([-+\/%=|!&<>(),\[\]])(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)/;

var arr = str.split(re);

console.log(arr)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:[^']*'){2}` finds a pair of single quotes
- `(([^']*'){2})*` finds 0 or more pair of quotes
- `[^']*$` makes sure we don't have any more quotes after last matched quote
- `(?=...)` asserts that we have even number of single quotes ahead thus matching special characters outside the single quoted string only.

Comment: correctly working for pair of single quotes as string. Will check it more. thanks @anubhava.
For more robustness can you suggest me some library for parsing and replacing variables inside string except esprima. I can't use esprima as I will need to support excel IF condition also.

Comment: Sorry not aware of parsing libraries but I will search and let you know.